# Query or filter the data when using date time format

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-dates

[Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hO_KatnkP58wuF6I7kwtlGgCI6xM6ubopgCwuYMXXIU/edit?usp=sharing).

Sheet2

In cell A2 I have:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:Q, "Select * where B >= datetime '"&TEXT($A$1,"MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss")&"'")
```

In cell A1 I have:

```
6/17/2020 10:53:22 AM
```

Sheet1:
Column A (user)       and        B (date and time)

```
A       B
-----------------------------
User1   6/17/2020 10:53:22 AM
User2   6/17/2020 10:53:22 AM
User3   6/17/2020 11:10:55 AM
User4   6/17/2020 11:33:57 AM
User5   6/24/2020 10:47:34 AM
User6   6/25/2020 4:50:39 AM
User7   6/24/2020 4:00:24 AM
User8   7/4/2020 5:44:25 AM
User9   7/4/2020 7:08:29 AM
User10  7/4/2020 8:49:24 AM
User11  7/3/2020 7:36:46 AM
```

The expected output in A2 Sheet2 is:

```
User1   6/17/2020 10:53:22 AM
User2   6/17/2020 10:53:22 AM
```

but the query I used outputs all of the data from Sheet 1.

Hope someone can help me...

Comment: Welcome. _The expected output in A2 Sheet2 is User 1 and User 2_. Why is the output only these two? Every user's timestamp is greater than  "6/17/2020 10:53:22 AM". Seems right to me that the results would be every user. Are you sure that you're not looking for "<=", or just "="??

Comment: My bad. Cell A1 should have: User11 7/3/2020 7:36:46 AM
and should show User8 7/4/2020 5:44:25 AM
User9 7/4/2020 7:08:29 AM
User10 7/4/2020 8:49:24 AM
User11 7/3/2020 7:36:46 AM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have UserID and date data in two columns. The date is expressed as "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM". You have a criterion cell for the date and time in the same format as the reference data. Your query output is all of the data rather than just those rows that satisfy the date criteria.

The reason that your query isn't working is because the string literal for date, datetime and timestamp does NOT include the AM/PM suffix [Doc ref](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#literals). When the suffix is removed from the data, the query works as expected.

This is the query:

`=query(revised_data!A2:B12,"select A, B where B >= datetime '"&TEXT(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss")&"'")`

---

**Raw Data**

[image: Input data]

**Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: Actually, it worked with AM and PM. Thank you so much!