# How to add date criteria to query function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-dates

I am using query function to copy all data from sheet1!A2:B10 to Sheet2 if B column is equal to specific data/time.
Lets say A1 = 5 April 2021
A2:A10 names
B2:B10 has Timestamp
And I used this formula

`Query(sheet1!A2:B10," select * where B=A1+31/24",0)`
which means query all data if B = 6 April 2021 07:00

But query doesn't accept such format. Any thoughts?
one Idea to create a column C where I put the date/time static (6 April 2021 07:00) and use `query(sheet1!A2:C10,"select * where B=C",0)`
but seems I have to convert column C to text as well..

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/143683/88163